# Similarity between signals

Tags: cross-correlation

Let's say we have two signals with fast ascending in the beginning, then one slowly decays while another remains at a constant level. An illustration plot is attached. How to compare the similarity between these two with an optimal metric? Cross-correlation seems insensitive to the delay and shape difference. Would dynamic time warping or some others be a better option?

Thank you
[image]

Comment: Is there an objective metric from **the domain** you are looking at (e.g. cardiovascular), that can answer if these two waveforms are similar or not? Otherwise, you can fit a general model from the max to the rest of the data and complement it by a simple estimation of the time interval between $t=0$ and the maximum.

Comment: This question has been asked and answer multiple times, have you tried searching this website with the  “similarity” keyword ?

Comment: @A_A The waves are from the measurement of drug kinetics in human body.